# Virtual Blackboard for Online Meetings

Tags: collaboration

I would like to integrate a "virtual blackboard" functionality with my e-learning website. I would like users to be able to participate in "meetings", with the following functionality:

- chat (optionaly voice chat/videochat)
- virtual blackboard (collaborative drawing)
- screensharing (so one of the users can present material like pictures to other users)
- ideally Flash or Java applet based (so users wouldn't have to install any additional software - but this is not a requirement, as long as setup wouldn't be too cumbersome)

I guess there are no free solutions, so I'm looking for a paid one. It would be best if users didn't have to set up separate accounts to participate in meetings. Perhaps they could just click on a link with the meeting id.

I googled a little and looked at Adobe Connect Pro. Are there any alternatives that you can recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout BigBlueButton http://www.bigbluebutton.org/

> BigBlueButton is an active open source
>   project that focuses on usability,
>   modularity, and clean design -- both
>   for the user and the developer. The
>   project is hosted at Google Code
>   http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to create one with only JavaScript. Then the user really doesn't have to install anything, unlike with Flash or Java.

A pretty good tutorial is [here](http://cristian.nexcess.net/ajax/whiteboard/), and additionally [*Ajax: The Definitive Guide*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528386) has a good tutorial around Ch. 20 ish.

Answer (score 0):

Influxis also has some Flash based meeting software apps and gives you the source code, so that you may extend them, if you are interested in that.

http://influxis.com/applications/